# getting the id from a table in database

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

i have 3 tables city, information and state. In my code i've shown the different cites under different state. what i want to do is to get the seperate ids of the cities so that i can run some queries in my 'information' table.

My model is given below:

```
  function get_status(){
$states = $this->db->get('state');
$like = array();
$status = array();
foreach ($states->result() as $state){
$cities = $this->db->get_where('city', array('state_id'=> $state->id));
$like=$cities->result();
$status=$like[0]->city_id;

   }

    echo $status;
  }
```

but when i run the code i only get the last id of the last city stored under the last state in the the table. for example the state 3 has city that has id 3. i'm only getting this id. but i want all the ids of the cities like- 1,2,3.

i'm using Codeigniter framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show me a var_dump($like); is it object?

Comment: @Dezigo the output of var_dump($like) is given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$like - it`s an array.
[0] - the first element of an array.

```
echo $like[0]->city_id;
```

I haven`t tested it. (In one iteration -> it takes all the cities from that ID)

```
 function get_status(){
        $states = $this->db->get('state');
        $like = array();
        $status = array();

    foreach ($states->result() as $state){
        $cities = $this->db->get_where('city', array('state_id'=> $state->id));
            foreach ($cities->result() as &$v){
                echo $v->city_id."<br/>";
            }
            echo "......<br/>";
       }
}
```

Comment: it works but the problem is that it only shows the id of the last city. but i want ids of all the cities. can u please tell why it is showing only the last id? the modification is given above.